# My 6 months old cat stopped cleaning itself. Help

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat used to be very clean, but suddenly stopped cleaning itself as usual. It's a Persian with medium to long hair, is causing poop stains every time it goes pooping, and its tail remains dirty until it is impossible to clean.

Can anyone help me have an effective solution? I usually feed it dry food all day and once or less a day of wet food.

Comment: Does your cat eat normal? Does it seem lethargic or less energetic? Is it still drinking?
How long have you had your cat?

Comment: A sudden change in cleaning behavior, particularly the cat not grooming and cleaning itself properly anymore, warrants a visit to the vet. This can be a sign of medical issues, and you do not want to wait for strangers on the internet to troubleshoot what could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Serena, my cat is Better today. Seems back to normal. It didn't stop eating nor drinking but in addition to diarrhea it vomited once. I had to give it flagile for babies and a serum in the water. It also lost normal energy. Thank God it seems to be over. I had it since March 2nd. It was 55 days old

Comment: Bgse. You are totally Right that's why it took me a while to reply. But in my country . Thanks